# Llamar una clase en python

Tags: python, poo

la pregunta que tengo creo que es bastante sencilla de resolver.
He visto otras preguntas en este foro en las que se habla sobre este tema, pero no de la misma manera, con la misma situación.

Mi pregunta es como llamar una clase desde otra clase. La teoría es la de siempre:
Por ejemplo:

```
class variables:
    variable1='Hola'

class saludar:
    print(variable1)
```

Aquí es facil. En una clase defino las variables con las que quiero trabajar. Y en la siguiente clase utilizo la función print para mostrarla.

¿Pero como lo podría hacer al revés? Si quiero hacerlo en otro orden, tengo errores.
Es decir. Primero poner la función print y luego que me extraiga las variables de clases posteriores.
Yo he probado con el siguiente codigo, pero no he consigo el resultado esperado:

```
class saludar:
    import variables as v
    x= v.variable1
    print(x)
class variables:
    variable1='Hola'
```

Si la clase variables la pusiera en un archivo .py aparte si que funcionaría. ¿Pero como lo hago para hacer lo mismo desde el mismo archivo?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: De la forma en que muestras simplemente no puedes ya que ña definición de la clase está después y no antes de la llamada

Comment: El código que muestras tiene errores y no ejecuta. Debes proporcionar un código ejecutable, mostrar sus resultados y preguntar en base a eso.

Comment: El ejemplo que pones como válido, tal cual está no funciona, produce un error del tipo: `NameError: name 'variable1' is not defined`. Te sugiero que seas más explícito en lo que deseas lograr, ya que no se entiende totalmente cuál es tu duda, y el ejemplo que pones da a entender que hay ciertos conceptos del lenguaje (y de la programación en si misma) que no tienes lo suficientemente afianzados. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da la sensación de que intentas hacer algo así:

```
class variables:
    variable1='hola'
class saludar:
    v=variables()
    print(v.variable1)
    
s=saludar()
```

Pero usas `import` en vez de crear un objeto de la clase que te interesa. Aunque tampoco llegas a instanciar las clases en ningún momento, así que tampoco me queda muy claro.

Si usaras el constructor `__init__` podrías pasarle un objeto externo como parámetro a tu clase, que puede ser lo que realmente intentas hacer. Sería algo así:

```
class variables:
    variable1='hola'
class saludar:
    def __init__(self,v):
        print(v.variable1)

v=variables()
v.variable1='mi nuevo valor'    
s=saludar(v)
```

Comment: Genial David! es justo lo que se me escapaba. Tienes toda la razón. Utilizar import en este caso no tenía sentido (lo hacia así porque antes lo hacía desde otro archivo .py). Pero lo ideal es utilizar el constructor _init_ tal como lo has explicado. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.